# kohana3.3 : do find_all() while {criteria for the 1st element} and echo the rest elements thereafter

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, kohana, kohana-3

I need this tricky thing to be done: 10 items to selected in a random manner, one item for true/false criteria and the rest nine items to echo :

```
$unique_items=array('bike', 'doll', 'carpet', 'postcard');

do {
   $items=ORM::factory('Shop')
     ->order_by(DB::expr('Rand()'))//this way I take 10 random rows from the table
     ->limit(10)
     ->find_all();
}while (in_array(first_item_from_ten_rows->name, $unique_items));

foreach ($items as $item){
   echo $item->name;//display 2nd, 3rd, ..., 10th items, without the first one
}
```

The php framework I use here is Kohana3.3

Comment: Whats the reason for such using first row?

Comment: The first row is the basic item among others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need to do:

```
$first = TRUE
foreach ($items as $item) 
{
   if ($first)
   {
      $first = FALSE;
   }
   else
   {
      echo $item->name;
   }
}
```